# Would the word "peoples" be used to mean many different cultures?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm writing a book, and I don't know if I'm using the word peoples right. I'm fairly sure it IS a word, but I don't know its exact use.

Comment: Yes, *peoples* is fine. But you can remove the word *many* from your title - it is presumably unnecessary for the question.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary? What are the various senses in which *peoples* can be used?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/605125/2085).

Answer (score 1):

That use seems fine, something like "ancient Europe was inhabited by peoples of varied language and cultural."

Wiktionary has: (plural peoples)  Persons forming or belonging to a particular group, such as a nation, class, ethnic group, country, family, etc; folk; community. [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/people)

Answer (score 0):

[Peoples](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/people) can be used with the meaning you are suggesting:

Usage Note:

> - As a term meaning "a body of persons sharing a culture," people is a singular noun, as in As a people the Pueblo were noteworthy for their peacefulness. **Its plural is peoples: the many and varied peoples of West Africa**. But when used to mean "humans," people is plural and has no corresponding singular form. English is not unique in this respect; Spanish, Italian, Russian, and many other languages have a plural word meaning "people" that has no singular.

an alternative can be

[Population(s)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Population) :

> The total number of inhabitants constituting a particular race, class, or group in a specified area.
>
> - A group of individuals of the same species occupying a particular geographic area. **Populations** may be relatively small and closed, as on an island or in a valley, or they may be more diffuse and without a clear boundary between them and a neighboring population of the same species. For species that reproduce sexually, the members of a population interbreed either exclusively with members of their own population or, where populations intergrade, to a greater degree than with members of other populations.

Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

"Peoples" is like "fishes." It refers to a plurality of distinct groups, not a plurality of individuals who form the group.